# Customize Template10 HamburgerMenu (Hamburger Icon Size & PaneOpen Width)

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I have read their documentation on GitHub and still have not found a way to change the hamburger icon height which matches the height of my own page header (Template10 Pageheader has fixed size that can't be changed that's why I made my own)

Furthermore I want the pane to completely open like any other UWP app.

I want the pane to be wide open like this:[Pane is open, page title/header shifting to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlZD5.png)

Too bad it looks like this
[Page title not shifting to the right and only the 'bottom' pane is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDuGx.png)

The XAML of the Shell:

```
<Page x:Class="Template10.Samples.VoiceAndInkSample.Views.Shell"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:Controls="using:Template10.Controls"
  xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
  xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="using:Template10.Samples.VoiceAndInkSample.Views"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:views="using:Template10.Samples.VoiceAndInkSample.Views" mc:Ignorable="d">

<Controls:ModalDialog IsModal="{x:Bind IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Controls:ModalDialog.Content>
        <Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu" IsFullScreen="False"
            HamburgerBackground="#EB690B"
            HamburgerForeground="White"
            NavAreaBackground="#EB690B"
            NavButtonBackground="#EB690B"
            SecondarySeparator="#EB690B"  
            NavButtonForeground="White" 
            NavButtonCheckedForeground="Black"
            NavButtonCheckedBackground="#EB690B"
            NavButtonCheckedIndicatorBrush="Black"
            VisualStateNormalDisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
            VisualStateNarrowDisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
            VisualStateWideDisplayMode="CompactOverlay">

            <Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
                <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo ClearHistory="True" PageType="views:MainPage">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Width="48" Height="48" Symbol="Home" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Home" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>

            <Controls:HamburgerMenu.SecondaryButtons>
                <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo PageType="views:SettingsPage">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <SymbolIcon Width="48" Height="48" Symbol="Setting" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Settings" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenu.SecondaryButtons>

        </Controls:HamburgerMenu>

    </Controls:ModalDialog.Content>
    <Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>

        <Viewbox Height="32">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ProgressRing Width="16" Height="16"
                              Margin="12,0" Foreground="White"
                              IsActive="{x:Bind IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind BusyText, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>

    </Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
</Controls:ModalDialog>
```

Comment: If your UWP app has target and min version set to the Fall Creators Update,  you are better using the NavigationView control, which is available for this SDK.

Comment: it is because you build your pane in bottom grid , please show your xaml

Comment: @AndréB I tried replacing Template10 Hamburger menu with the NavigationView control, but somehow the app closes right before the splashscreen shows up

Comment: @ShubhamSahu I don't build the Hamburger Menu. Like I said, it's from the Tenmplate 10 and I want to customize it now. 

XAML can now be found in the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the height of the HamburgerButton with the current version of Template10 as it is hardcoded. [Height definition in the source](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/f5d5e6339ed72685b5043b6fb9fa2b4abf63f288/Controls/Template10.Controls.Hamburger/Controls.HamburgerMenu/HamburgerMenu.xaml#L463)

You could either fork and define your own height or (if you can target the latest Windows 10 release) use the new `NavigationView` instead.

As for making it look "completely open", first you'd have to use the `Inline` DisplayMode instead of the `CompactOverlay` you're currently using. Then you'd have to set the `HamburgerBackground` color of the HamburgerMenu to the same color set for `NavAreaBackground`. This way you'd get the effect of full height. On how to apply those colors, please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48191898/5604534).